# Django can't search "method not allowed"

Tags: python, html, django, url, redirect

im new to django and im currently doing a website for my friend. he wants me to make a system where the users can search the database and the website gives the relevent items according to their serial number.
i followed a tutorial from the following site: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-search-tutorial to figure out how to do db searchs which helped a lot, but im still having a problem: my search bar works, and the result page also works but it only works when i manually type the query on the searchbar myself (e.x. results/?q=number1). However when i search using the input bar and the submit button it sends me to /results/ page and the page gives this:

This page isn’t working

If the problem continues, contact the site owner.

HTTP ERROR 405

-when i open up pycharm to see the error in terminal it says:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /result/

Method Not Allowed: /result/

[27/Oct/2020 20:06:02] "POST /result/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

here are my codes(python3.7,pycharm) websites/urls:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('', views.IndexViews.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('scan/', views.ScanView.as_view(), name='scan'),
    path('result/', views.SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='result'),
]
```

websites/views:

```
class IndexViews(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "websites/index.html"
    context_object_name = "object_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Website.objects.all()


class ScanView(TemplateView):
    form_class = SerialFrom
    template_name = 'websites/scan.html'


class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = SerialNumber
    template_name = 'websites/result.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        object_list = SerialNumber.objects.filter(
            Q(number__iexact=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

scan.html:

```
 {% extends 'websites/base.html' %}
{% block albums_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="box" action="{% url 'result' %}" method="POST">
      <h1>Product Check</h1>
        <p> Please enter the serial id of your product to check it.</p>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Serial Number">
      <input type="submit" name="q" placeholder="Check">
  </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

thank you for taking your time and reading, please help me i really need to do this.

Comment: The reason GET is used for searching and not POST, is that searching does not alter anything in the application or it's database. It is identical to a listing (ListView), except it gives the user the option to reduce the items in the list to something more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) by default does not implement a handler for a POST request. Searching is normally done through a GET request, so you should use:

```
<form class="box" action="{% url 'result' %}" method="GET">
    <h1>Product Check</h1>
    <p> Please enter the serial id of your product to check it.</p>
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Serial Number">
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Check">
</form>
```

Furthermore the `<input type="submit">` should not have a `name="q"` attribute.

As [@Melvyn says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559649/django-cant-search-method-not-allowed/64559696?noredirect=1#comment114155651_64559696), you can also alter the type to [**`type="search"`** [mozilla]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search) for the text box:

```
<form class="box" action="{% url 'result' %}" method="GET">
    <h1>Product Check</h1>
    <p> Please enter the serial id of your product to check it.</p>
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Serial Number">
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Check">
</form>
```

Comment: Use [type="search"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search) for browser-specific enhancements and semantically more accurate. It's a minor difference though.

Comment: Thank you so much! after a whole day of searching i finally did it!

Comment: @tyler: did you remove the `name="q"` from the button? If not, it will (likely) add an extra `&q=` at the end, and thus the `q` object will be empty.